# Is there a way to have a fading warning with Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a message saying "Saved!" when you click the save button. It works right now but then just stays there. Is there any command that allows for it to fade away?

```
            http.put(that.url, that.transactionFees()).then(function (response) {
            if (response.Id) {
                alert ('Saved!');
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for. Fade out after 500ms, Using jQuery.
`$('.alert').delay(500).fadeOut('slow')`

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is using jQuery. Are you using a JS framework?